# Yii2 Form Submission TroubleShoot

Tags: php, forms, yii2

So I'm displaying the logged user's information on a page, followed by a form which can be used to change basic user info, such as e-mail address, username and so on.

In the ProfileController file, I have the Index action, which handles the user info and, theoretically, the form too:

```
public function actionIndex() {

    $user = User::find()->where(['id' => Yii::$app->user->identity->id])->one();

    if ($user->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        $user->save();
        //var_dump($user->first_name);die;
    } 

    return $this->render('index', [ 
            'user' => $user,
    ]);
}
```

In the index view file, I'm displaying the form as it follows:

```
                 <div class="row form">

                    <div class="user-form col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                        <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

                        <?= $form->field($user, 'last_name')->textInput(['maxLength' => true]) ?>

                        <?= $form->field($user, 'first_name')->textInput(['maxLength' => true]) ?>

                        <?= $form->field($user, 'email')->textInput(['maxLength' => true]) ?>

                        <?= $form->field($user, 'image')->textInput([]) ?>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <?= Html::submitButton('Submit', ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
                        </div>

                        <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
                    </div>

                </div>
```

Problem is, whenever I press the submit button beneath the form, the controller receives the post request, but does not update the new values given in the form fields, thus displaying the old info at the var_dump(). What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably validation failed. Proper way of doing this is:

```
// ...
if ($user->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
    if ($user->save()) {
        // validated and saved, check $user state now
    }
}
```

Method `save()` calls method `validate()` automatically. You can call it on your own as well if you want to operate on this model only when it's validated.

Comment: var_dumped() the fields I tried to modify again, still has no effect :'(.

Comment: Where did you put var_dump?

Comment: Inside the if ($user->save()) {}

Comment: So you are saying that you changed `first_name` value in the form's input, it's been properly validated and saved in the database, and `var_dump($user->first_name);die;` shows the old value?

Comment: Did you set validation rules,also setting safe the variables that have not rules?You mean that db is not updating?

Comment: It does not save it in the database. The old values remain everywhere. Sorry for not specifying this earlier.

Comment: @dimis283 you're brilliant. Thanks so much.

Comment: I've updated the rules in the model and now everything works properly. Thanks for your time c:.